# Efficiently dropping 2 bits from a 32bit data type

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Assume you have a 32bit data type:

```
// The letters are just to identify the position of each bit later in the post
abcdefgh ijklmnop qrstuvwx yzABCDEF
```

I'm logging for the most efficient way to "drop" bits at certain locations, where dropping means "removing" the given bits, and moving the following bits to fill in its place.

Example: Let's say I want to drop bits "a" and "q". Then the result should look either like:

```
bcdefghi jklmnopr stuvwxyz ABCDEF00
```

or

```
00bcdefg hijklmno prstuvwx yzABCDEF
```

Either result would be acceptable.

In my specific case, I can also impose the following constraints:

- The positions to drop are static in my case; i.e. I will always need to drop exactly the 1st and 16th bit ("a" and "q")
- The bits to be dropped ("a" and "q") are always 0
- The bits that end up padding the data (the "00" to the left or right after the operation) don't matter - i.e., doesn't matter if they're actually 0 or 1

Currently I'm using an approach like this (pseudo-code):

```
// called with number = abcdefgh ijklmnop qrstuvwx yzABCDEF
auto drop_bits_1_16(unsigned int number)
{
    number = number << 1; // number becomes: bcdefghi jklmnopq rstuvwxy zABCDEF0
    unsigned number1 = number & 0xFFFE0000;  // number1 comes: bcdefghi jklmnop0 00000000 00000000

    unsigned number2 = number & 0x0000FFFF; // number2 becomes: 00000000 00000000 rstuvwxy zABCDEF0
    number2 = number2 << 1;  // number2 becomes: 00000000 0000000r stuvwxyz ABCDEF00

    return number1 | number2;  // returns bcdefghi jklmnopr stuvwxyz ABCDEF00
}
```

but I'm wondering if there's any more clever/efficient way out there?

Comment: If there was a clever "bit hack", it would feature in [Sean E. Anderson](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)'s compilation more likely than not.

Comment: If you can live with a zero on either sides, `number + (unsigned short)number`  ;-)

Comment: Actually, you're dropping either bits 1 and 17, or 0 and 16, depending on if you're 0-based or 1-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packing to the right is slightly easier than packing to the left, as only 15 bits have to move, instead of two times 15. I don't see how masking can be voided, so

```
((number & 0x7FFF0000) >> 1) | (number & 0x00007FFF)
```

This doesn't require the discarded bits to be zeroes. There are four bitwise operations, less will be difficult.

---

There is a way in three operations !

Add the 15 low-order bits to shift them left one position (multiplies by 2), and right shift the whole.

```
(number + (number & 0x7FFF)) >> 1
```

Caution: bit 15 must be a zero.

Maybe the following expression will give the compiler some options for better code generation:

```
(number + (unsigned short)number) >> 1
```

Should I add that the other final layout is also possible ?

```
(number + (unsigned short)number) << 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this is correct. Even if you replace `0xFFFF` with `0xFFFF0000`. See the second snippet of my answer.

Comment: Well I have to say, I'm impressed with the last expression. Apparently, it takes the number of assembler instructions from 5 down to 3. Not sure how much faster it is though, since the instructions are different. Also not very readable, but whatever. Nice one.

Comment: Nice, that's a very clever solution .. Thanks @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the other way:

```
auto drop_bits_1_16(unsigned int number)
{
    unsigned number1 = number & 0x7FFF0000; // number1 becomes: 0bcdefgh ijklmnop 00000000 00000000
    unsigned number2 = number & 0x00007FFF; // number2 becomes: 00000000 00000000 0rstuvwx yzABCDEF
    number1 = number1 >> 1; // number1 becomes: 00bcdefg hijklmno p0000000 00000000

    return number1 | number2;  // returns 00bcdefg hijklmno prstuvwx yzABCDEF
}
```

That's shorter and has the advantage of being more readable: it's clear what bits are dropped from the bitmasks.

You can also make it a one-liner:

```
auto drop_bits_1_16(unsigned int number)
{
    return ((number & 0x7FFF0000) >> 1) | (number & 0x00007FFF);
    // Or, relying on operator precedence:
    // return (number & 0x7FFF0000) >> 1 | number & 0x00007FFF;
}
```

Which is arguably more clear than what your solution becomes as a one-liner:

```
auto drop_bits_1_16(unsigned int number)
{
    return ((number << 1) & 0xFFFE0000) | (((number << 1) & 0x0000FFFF) << 1);
    // Or, relying on operator precedence:
    // return number << 1 & 0xFFFE0000 | (number << 1 & 0x0000FFFF) << 1;
}
```

Or, as suggested by @greybeard (but still arguably less clear):

```
auto drop_bits_1_16(unsigned int number)
{
    return ((number << 1) & 0xFFFE0000) | ((number << 2) & 0x0001FFFC);
    // Or, relying on operator precedence:
    // return number << 1 & 0xFFFE0000 | number << 2 & 0x0001FFFC;
}
```

Comment: (You could make the one-liner of the original code `return ((number << 1) & 0xFFFE0000) | ((number << 2) & 0x0001FFFC);`.)

Comment: @ruakh Yeah I think my mind skipped a step there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this generic solution.  From what I can see there needs to be 3 parts.

Removing bits 3 and 20 say. (zero based)

```
3
1            v                     v  0
hhhh hhhh hhhx mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm xlll
```

You need to mask out the low. medium and high parts, then squish them together.

```
template <size_t low, size_t hi> unsigned int remove_bits(unsigned int all)
{
    // static constants - my compiler pre-computes them.  They are the masks for
    // hhhh, mmmm and llll
    static const unsigned int lowMask = 0x7fffffff >> (31 - low);
    static const unsigned int middleMask = ((0xfffffffe << low) & (0x7fffffff >> (31 - hi) ));
    static const unsigned int highMask = 0xfffffffe << hi;

    // find the values in hhhh, mmmm, and llll
    unsigned int resLow = (all & lowMask);
    unsigned int resMiddle = (all & middleMask);
    unsigned int resHigh = (all & highMask);

    //////////////////////////////////////
    // combine the parts, shifted to the lower end.

    return resLow | resMiddle >> 1 | resHigh >> 2;
}
```

Call using something like

```
printf("Question q %x\n", remove_bits<1, 31>(0x12345678));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing simpler than the specified implementation:

```
unsigned int drop_bits_16_32(unsigned int number)
{
    number <<= 1;
    unsigned int high = number & 0xFFFE0000;
    unsigned int low = (number & 0x0000FFFF) << 1;

    return high | low;
}
```

Comment: Then why repeat it?

Comment: Yes, there is simpler, you can spare two operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the version where bits are dropped on the left with 4 instead of 5 instructions:

```
unsigned f1(unsigned x) {
    x <<= 1;
    return x + ((signed) (x << 15) >> 15);
}
```

Note the signed right shift which replicates the bit to be removed such that it cancels out in the add.

Comment: Solutions with four and even three instructions are already available (even "two and a half").

Comment: Not for the version that drops the bits to the left, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, for both. Read the whole post.

Comment: True, I missed the extra information that the bits to be dropped are always 0. This solution works independent of that condition.